# Date serialization in spring MVC

Tags: java, json, spring, date, serialization

in my json output Date is rendred as Object, so testing with Postman throw an error: Expected 'u' instead of 'e'

```
{
    "ao_id":6,
    "code":"AOO N°199-2017 C/T",
    "objet":"Marché Cadre - Travaux de réfection de voiries",
    "date_saisie":new Date(1514851200000)
    }
```

I annotated my entity class with:

```
 @Column(name = "date_saisie")
    @JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd")
    private Date date_saisie
```

How to correctly serialize my date object..
thx,

Comment: Try `@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd)`

Comment: i tried also:  @JsonFormat(
           shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING,
           pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss")
              private Date date_saisie;  and it didn't work

Answer (score 2):

An ideal way would be to configure this with following Jackson configuration -

`objectMapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);`

This will make sure that all of the dates are serialized in a consistent format.

Below is the complete configuration for your reference -

```
public class JacksonMapper extends ObjectMapper
{
    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(JacksonMapper.class);

    public JacksonMapper()
    {
        this.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);

        this.disable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
        this.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);

        this.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);

        this.registerModules(new Jdk8Module()); // Enables support for JDK 8 data types e.g. Optional
        this.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule()); // Enables serialization of Java 8 timestamps
    }
}
```

Use following XML configuration for creating bean of objectmapper -

`<bean id="objectMapper" class="config.JacksonMapper" />`

Comment: i'm using a rest controller, where to put your code : 
                   @RequestMapping(value="getAppelOffre", method=RequestMethod.GET,  produces = "application/json;charset=UTF-8")
 public ResponseEntity<AppelOffre> getAOById(@RequestParam("id") int id) {
  System.out.println("fetching ao with id: "+id);
  
  AppelOffre ao = service.getAppelOffreById(id);
  
  System.out.println("date is: "+ao.getDate_saisie());
  return new ResponseEntity<AppelOffre>(ao, HttpStatus.OK);
 }

Comment: You should put this code in your Java file responsible for spring configuration. I assume you are using Java based spring configuration.

Comment: i'm using xml based spring config instead

Comment: In that case I have updated by answer for XML based configuration